# macro help with $\mathbb{Z}/p^{a}\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: macros

I am using `\mathbb{Z}/p^{a}\mathbb{Z}` many times in my work with variable `a`, I was thinking can I define a macro like `\Z_p^{a}` which will give the above result. I tried

```
\newcommand{\Z_p}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}/p^{#1}\mathbb{Z}}}
```

but LaTeX did not like it.

Comment: Names of TeX macros defined via `\def` or `\newcommand` must consist of either one or more "letter"-class characters (A-Z and a-z) or exactly one non-letter character. The macro name `Z_p`, which contains two letter-class characters and one nonletter-class character -- is not valid under TeX's syntax rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd go with

```
\newcommand{\Zp}[1]{\mathbb{Z}/p^{#1}\mathbb{Z}}
```

and `$\Zp{a}$` will do what you want. It's not possible to have `_` in the name of a macro (unless playing nasty and fragile tricks).

Maybe I'd do

```
\newcommand{\Zp}[2][p]{\mathbb{Z}/#1^{#2}\mathbb{Z}}
```

so, for the case where you want to use a different prime you can type

```
\Zp[q]{a}
```

Why not `\ensuremath`? Because it serves little purpose; I find it much better to segregate math in the proper way, that is, between `$` symbols or inside `\(...\)`.

If you already have

```
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
```

it's better doing

```
\newcommand{\Zp}[2][p]{\Z/#1^{#2}\Z}
```

so a change of formatting for the integers will automatically produce the same change in `\Zp`. Better yet, I usually advice to do something like

```
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\numberset{Q}}
% ... other possible number sets ...

\newcommand{\Zp}[2][p]{\Z/#1^{#2}\Z}
```

so uniformity is ensured for all alike symbols.

Comment: Why is changing the catcode of `_` fragile?

Comment: @1010011010 Would you like being also able to use subscripts in math? Yes, it can be done, I know, but I classify this as a nasty and fragile trick, as some packages may expect `_` has its normal category code.

Comment: @egreg Wouldn't that also lead to incompatibilities with LaTeX3?

Comment: @1010011010 Not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

With Plain TeX syntax you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\def\Z_p#1{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}/p^{#1}\mathbb{Z}}}

\begin{document}

\Z_p {137}% or Z_p{137}, it's all up to you

\end{document}
```

Notice that this overwrites a previous command `\Z` if it exists, but by default none exist. To be extra sure with other packages loaded, insert

```
\newcommand\Z{}
```

before the `\def` to give a chance to LaTeX to protest.

[image]

Comment: I would bet that the OP has `\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}`

Comment: @egreg perhaps but why didn't he use `\Z` in his/her ensuremath then? and I recommend `\ZZ`...